# Transition from HTML login to Next Screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a website with a Login/Username&Password landing page. I'm have a div that contains the login area. It's set to visible, it spans 100% of page height and width, and its z-index is higher than any other element in the website. This gives the effect of a stand-alone log in page, but it's just a div containing the log in form that covers/overlaps the rest of the website.

When the user enters the correct username and password, I run a function to make this div `display:none;`, which hides the log in form and the user can then see and access the website.

This doesn't seem like the most secure way to handle the log in process, since the rest of the page elements underneath the log in form are being loaded in the background, before the user has even signed in.

What is the best way to handle the process of switching from a log in form to a logged-in website state in a secure way? I would rather not redirect the user to a new page if it's possible to keep them on the current page then that would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

When you first load the page in a unlogged-in state. You could load some dummy elements that has nothing to do with the user. On top of that then is the login form.

When a successful login is made a request is also made to the backend to request real data for the user. With this real data you modify the 'dummy elements' or simply generate new ones that are needed for the user through javascript.

So if you tried to use `display: none;` in the developer console to view the logged in version you wouldn't actually see anything of use.